# ASP.NET MVC - Dynamic dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one complicated issue here. Here's the desired interface :

[image]

When you click on `Add grade` a select and input.text is added with javascript. The problem here is **how** do you transfer all this to the controller ??
Here are the models used :

```
public class Student {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Grades")]
    public virtual IList<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}


public class Grade {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Class")]
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}


public class Class {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before ?

Comment: what you already try? you should use js anyway for this thing

Comment: see this tutorial it will help you http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html

Comment: @Zaki Indians are the best. That's exacly what I want, thanks ;)

Comment: By the way, it's David Beckham, not Beckam. :)

Comment: @ataravati Yep my bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Zaki's comment :
http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html

A thorough explanation of Model Binding to Lists :
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/